# Referencing Caliburn.Micro in foreground project that also has a BackgroundAgent

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

**Dumb: Answered below. Useful for posterity, I guess.**

I would have thought this would be a common occurrence and I'd find some information regarding this but no luck with searching so far.

I have a simple project that uses Caliburn.Micro. I split out some shared **non-Caliburn-dependent** code in a shared library (`Core`). I then created a background agent and referenced Core **only**. I'm also required to reference the background agent project in my foreground project(s).

**Only my foreground projects depend on Caliburn**.

The app builds, runs, and my agent runs on my phone. However, XAP validation fails:

```
[ERROR]: Unsupported API cannot be used by a background agent. Assembly Caliburn.Micro.dll was trying to use [whatever]
```

Now, I understand if my shared library was calling Caliburn but it has no dependency, it's simply that Caliburn is included in the `bin\Release` and inside the XAP.

I can't believe **no one** has released a Caliburn-powered app that didn't have a background agent, so how can I solve this? I can understand splitting out Unsupported API code into a separate library, but no code called from the agent *or* `Core` calls Caliburn APIs.

For reference, my project structure:

```
Core
 ^
 |_______________BackgroundAgent    
 |_WP71___v________^          ^
 |        |                   |
 |_WP80 __|___________________|
          v
       Caliburn
```

Sorry for the ASCII art.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh God, I'm an idiot.

For posterity:

If you have *previously* referenced Caliburn in your BackgroundAgent since you, like me, weren't as well-informed, **CLEAN THE WHOLE SOLUTION**. After cleaning all the bin directories, XAP validation passes now.

Ugh.